# Prevent Vue application from running if there is a typescript error

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm using VueJS with Typescript and I want strict error checking.

For example, I want to fail to build a project if there is a reference to some non-existent property somewhere in the code.

I have a code that triggers that error:

```
    const a = {};
    window.console.log(a.p);
```

I start my app with:

```
npm run serve
```

It prints an error to console:

```
ERROR in /home/x/nd/test/src/exp/Grav.vue(39,26):
39:26 Property 'p' does not exist on type '{}'.
    37 | 
    38 |     const a = {};
  > 39 |     window.console.log(a.p)

Version: typescript 3.9.7
Time: 413ms

  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 
  - Network: http://192.168.0.18:8080/
```

But app is still running on localhost and works completely fine.

How to prevent it to build when I'm running `npm run serve`?

My configs:

.eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/typescript/recommended'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
    project: "./tsconfig.json",
    createDefaultProgram: true,
  },
  rules: {
    "no-throw-literal": "error",
    "no-return-await": "error",

    "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/return-await": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars-experimental": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/unbound-method": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-throw-literal": ["error"],
    
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off'
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "allowJs": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,

    "noEmitOnError": true,

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer at https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5014. You need to disable the `async` option in https://github.com/TypeStrong/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin#options

To do that I created a file `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugin('fork-ts-checker').tap(options => {
      options[0].async = false
      return options
    })
  }
}
```